# How does a user get data about a signer by a public key?

Tags: java, android, keystore

I know that when the keystore file generates a pair of keys is generated: public key(modulus and an exponent), private key(exponent). But also when jks is generated, different fields have to be filled: company name,country, etc... How is this data stored in the jks file? Or it just adds to apk file when signing?